# Facebook settings for posting music to Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an app to post music to the Facebook timeline, but having problems when I POST as recommended in the doc.  I use OAuth 2 to successfully get the user's Facebook ID and a valid session_token, but then, when I post this...

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/music.listens?song=<song's URL>&expires_in=<seconds>&access_token=<session_token>
```

I get the following error message back from Facebook:

> {\"error\":{\"message\":\"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\"

So far...

- I've ruled out invalid and expired tokens.
- I'm requesting (and receiving) multiple permissions, including publish_checkins, publish_stream, user_likes, friends_likes, and create_event.
- I've set up all of my metatags according to the Facbook's OpenGraph music documentation.

At this point, it *seems* that all of the permissions, tokens, etc. are in order.  Are there some Application settings (possibly related to the "og" namespace) that need to be set?  Other permissions that need to be requested?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGraph Music music.listens returns error](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7602579/opengraph-music-music-listens-returns-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be whitelisted to use that feature (per the intro in the OG Music doc). To apply to be whitelisted, follow the instructions in the Open Graph [Builtin Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#listen) docs. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced enough to give you good answers, but I can tell you how I dealt with my oauth errors and see if they're of any help to you.

1. One of my errors came from when after I initialized the app (javascript sdk). I tried to post to timeline before facebook had completed the initialization and authorizationn process. I then edited the my post to timeline function to wait until facebook had responded before executing.
2. My other errors were from silly mistakes where I hadn't properly defined the actions and objects in my application settings yet. I didn't check the advanced options in the action type and object settings to find the exact url the objects resided in.
3. Does your url have & signs in them? The api seems to treat & signs as parameter separators. In my urls, I replaced &variable= with :variable= and reseparated the url parameters afterwards to ensure my parameters didn't get cut off.

Hope at least some of that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the Facebook Debugger? 
(they just changed the name & URL)

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Just paste your URL (or Access Token) in the field and click "Debug". It doesn't find all issues but it will point out any obvious problems and explains how to fix them.

If you don't see your problem/fix there, let us know!